# Maintain custom tick labels when using `c.trellis`

Tags: r, lattice, trellis

I have two trellis objects which I would like to combine using `c.trellis` from **latticeExtra** (the two figures can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/de6e5x2kyoy7owi/AADMuynAfmaU9r7SLkAaMBV5a?dl=0)). As you can see below, the resulting plot inherits the tick labels from the first figure, whereas the labels from the second figure are discarded. Is it possible to keep different y-axis tick labels when using `c.trellis`?

```
library(latticeExtra)

rsq_plt <- readRDS("rsq.rds")
err_plt <- readRDS("err.rds")

latticeExtra:::c.trellis(rsq_plt, err_plt, layout = c(1, 2))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: `c.trellis` will combine your 2 trellis objects into one - with a single set of labels, etc. I'd suggest `print.trellis` to display multiple trellis objects. See especially the first example in `?print.trellis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, it seems like I finally came up with a proper solution thanks to the comprehensive customization options for trellis plots. Disabling `scales` in the upper plot (via `scales = list(draw = FALSE)`; note that the file 'rsq.rds' has changed online) prior to performing `c.trellis` and subsequently `update`-ing the combined plot with customized y-axes solved the issue.

```
## combine plots and increase left padding
plt <- latticeExtra:::c.trellis(rsq_plt, err_plt, layout = c(1, 2))
plt <- update(plt, 
              scales = list(draw = FALSE), 
              par.settings = list(
                layout.widths = list(left.padding = 6, right.padding = 0), 
                layout.heights = list(top.padding = 0, bottom.padding = 0)
              ))

## custom panel.axis
panel.fun <- function(...) {

  # allow to draw labels outside panel
  trellis.par.set("clip", list(panel = "off", strip = "off"))

  # add upper y-axis
  if (panel.number() == 1) {
    panel.axis("left", at = 1, tck = .5, outside = TRUE,
               labels = expression("r"^2))
    panel.abline(v = 1, lty = 3, lwd = 1, col = "red")
    panel.dotplot(lwd = .5, ...)
  }

  # add lower y-axis
  if (panel.number() == 2) {
    panel.axis("left", at = 2:4, outside = TRUE, tck = .5,
               labels = c("MAE", "ME", "RMSE"))
    panel.abline(v = 0, lty = 3, lwd = 1, col = "red")
    panel.dotplot(..., lwd = 0.5)
  }
}

## apply custom axes
update(plt, panel = panel.fun)
```

[image: solution]